# How to refresh PHP scripted page with Javascript

Tags: javascript, php

How can I refresh echo using javascript?
I have something like this:

```
<?php
$today = time();  
$todayStr = date('D');
$summerS = mktime(0,0,0,2,0,date('Y'));
$summerE = mktime(0,0,0,12,21,date('Y'));
$close = mktime(17,0,0,date('n'),date('j'),date('Y'));
if ($today >= $summerS && $today <= $summerE)
{
    if ($todayStr == "Sat")
    {
        $open = mktime(8,0,0,date('n'),date('j'),date('Y'));
        if ($today >= $open && $today <= $close)
        {          
            $openT = "Otevřeno";
        }
        else
        {
            $nextO = date("H:i:s",($open - $today));
            $openT = "Zavřeno";
        }
    }
    elseif ($todayStr == "Sun")
    {
        $open = mktime(8,0,0,date('n'),date('j'),date('Y'));
        if ($today >= $open && $today <= $close)
        {          
            $openT = "otevřeno";
        }
        else
        {
            $nextO = date("H:i:s",($open - $today));
            $openT = "zavřeno";
        }
    }...

<p>Právě je <?php echo $openT ?></p>
```

And I don't even know how to refresh that echo in < p > to showing time by second.

Comment: It would be a better approach to just use Javascript for this. Would this be okay for you aswell ?

Comment: you can use `innerhtml` method https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_html_innerhtml.asp

Comment: Do you have much else on this page? Are you ok with using JavaScript to fully reload the page each second? Or better yet, would you consider rewriting your logic in JavaScript? That would definitely perform better, since it would save the round trip time to the server and back each second, and everything you've shown here in PHP could be done in JavaScript.

Comment: Yeah.. I'll do my best in rewriting. This is just it nothing else. So rewrite it won't be problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't "refresh" echo with javascript as the echo code executes on the server and the javascript executes in the browser.

Your two best options are:

- Do all the calculations you do in your PHP in client side Javascript
- Create a webservice that returns your $openT value and call that endpoint with AJAX in the browser